# validation/training accuracy and overfitting

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, training-data

If we randomly split the data into training data and validation data, and assume the training data and validation data have similar "distributions", i.e. they are both good representations of the whole data set.

In this case, should the validation accuracy always be roughly the same as the training accuracy if there is no overfitting? Or is it possible that, for some cases, there could exist a gap between the training and validation accuracy that is not due to overfitting or bad representation of the validation data?

If such gap exists, how to tell the gap between the training and validation accuracy is caused by overfitting or other reasons?

Comment: could you provide more context to the meaning of "intrinsic"? are you only asking for the case when training acc > validation acc, or the other way around as well?

Comment: @pietz by "intrinsic", I mean the gap that's NOT due to overfitting or bad representation of the validation data. I have removed the word "intrinsic" to avoid confusing.

Answer (score 1):

"Is there anything other than" questions are often hard to answer, but I would argue that a higher accuracy on the training data is always due to overfitting or chance.

- The validation accuracy is often higher at the end of an epoch, because the training accuracy is usually calculated as a moving average during the epoch
- When using heavy amounts of image augmentation you also sometimes see a better performance on the validation data because it wasn't modified like the training data

These two don't really count and if I understand correctly you're asking for a situation where the training accuracy is higher without overfitting or chance playing a role. I don't think such a reason exists.